# Prove that $E[Y_1 + Y_2\mid X=x] $...

Tags: probability

Let $Y_1,Y_2,X$ be random variables

I want to prove that $E[Y_1 + Y_2 \mid X =x] = E[Y_1 \mid X= x] + E[Y_2 \mid X=x]$

I'll do it in the discrete case as follows;

$$\sum_{y_1} \sum_{y_2} (y_1 + y_2) P_{Y_1 +Y_2 \mid X =x}(y_1 + y_2)$$
$$  = \sum_{y_1} y_1 \sum_{y_2}  \big( P_{Y_1+  Y_2 \mid X =x}(y_1 + y_2)  \big) +  \sum_{y_2}  y_2  \sum_{y_1}  \big( P_{Y_1+ Y_2 \mid X =x}(y_1 + y_2)  \big ) $$
$$=  \sum_{y_1} y_1  P_{Y_1 \mid X =x}(y_1)  +  \sum_{y_1} y_2  P_{Y_1 \mid X =x}(y_2)      $$

what I am unsure about is this equality ("marginal conditional probability");

$$P_{Y_1 \mid X =x}(y_1) = \sum_{y_2}  \big( P_{Y_1+  Y_2 \mid X =x}(y_1 + y_2)  \big)$$

Can someone correct me? Looking at the definition of conditional expectation I think I am really wrong here with the double sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the discrete case the double sum uses the joint probability mass, not the probability of the sum.  It's not the same thing.
$$\mathsf E[S+T\mid \cdot] = \sum_s\sum_t (s+t)\mathsf P_{S,T\mid\cdot}(s,t\mid \cdot) \color{red}{\neq \sum_s\sum_t (s+t) \mathsf P_{S+T\mid \cdot}(s+t\mid \cdot)}$$

This is done via the Law of Total Probability:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[S+T\mid \cdot] & = \sum_n n \mathsf P(S+T=n\mid \cdot)
\\ & = \sum_n n \sum_s \mathsf P(S+T=n, S=s\mid \cdot)
\\ & = \sum_s \sum_n (s+(n-s)) \mathsf P(S=s, T=n-s\mid \cdot)
\\ & = \sum_s \sum_t (s+t)\mathsf P(S=s,T=t\mid \cdot)
\end{align}$$

Then your proof becomes: 
$$\begin{align}
 \mathsf E[Y_1+Y_2\mid X=x]
 & = \sum_{y_1} \sum_{y_2} (y_1+y_2) \mathsf P_{Y_1,Y_2\mid X}(y_1,y_2\mid x)
\\[1ex]
 & = \sum_{y_1}y_1\sum_{y_2} \mathsf P_{Y_1,Y_2\mid X}(y_1,y_2\mid x) +\sum_{y_2}y_2\sum_{y_1} \mathsf P_{Y_1,Y_2\mid X}(y_1,y_2\mid x) 
\\[2ex]\text{The first term is:}
\\[1ex]
 \sum_{y_1}y_1\sum_{y_2} \mathsf P_{Y_1,Y_2\mid X}(y_1,y_2\mid x) & = \sum_{y_1}y_1\sum_{y_2} \mathsf P_{Y_1\mid X}(y_1\mid x)\mathsf P_{Y_2\mid Y_1,X}(y_2\mid y_1, x)
\\[1ex]
 & = \sum_{y_1}y_1 \mathsf P_{Y_1\mid X}(y_1\mid x)\sum_{y_2}\mathsf P_{Y_2\mid Y_1,X}(y_2\mid y_1, x)
\\[1ex]
 & = \sum_{y_1}y_1 \mathsf P_{Y_1\mid X}(y_1\mid x)
\\ & = \mathsf E[Y_1\mid X=x]
\\[2ex]
 \text{Symmetrically for the other term}
\\[1ex]
 \sum_{y_2}y_2\sum_{y_1} \mathsf P_{Y_1,Y_2\mid X}(y_1,y_2\mid x) & = \mathsf E[Y_2\mid X=x]
\\[3ex]
\therefore \mathsf E[Y_1+Y_2\mid X=x]
 & = \mathsf E[Y_1\mid X=x]+\mathsf E[Y_2\mid X=x]
\end{align}$$